# dataProvider How to Point for a specific Object(Not by Index)

Tags: actionscript-3, indexing, dataprovider

How to Point for an Object in DataProvider, using specified id that is already in that object array.
Like for example, DataProvider contains an object - that has some properties: path/address to a model('testHouse/testHouseMD2.md2'), and ID("20") of it.

Can I access Using `getItemAt(index("20").address` method? Or it can be used only to get object by index, like for example this object has ID("20") but it index could point to "5" so when I put "20" in getItemAt, I get completely wrong object.

Or its need to be created a own method to access object property(ID) to be used as `pointer(Index)` for address?
If so please help me out what constructors could be used - PLEASE!!

Answer (score 0):

You should encapulate the access to the objects:

```
const _map:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
const _collection:IList = new ArrayCollection();

function add(object:Object = null):Object {
  if (!object) return null;
  _map[object.id] = object;
  _collection.addItem(object);
  return object;
}

function getById(id:String):Object {
  if (!id) return null;
  return  object[id];
}

function getAt(index:uint):Object {
  if (index < 0) return null;
  return _collection.getItemAt(index);
}
```

If you are working with classes - which is recommended, you should created typed interfaces for those collections to reduce the number of possible access errors.

Instead of the ArrayCollection you might be using something like this:

```
package io.floriansalihovic.collections {

  import flash.events.Event;
  import flash.events.IEventDispatcher;
  import flash.utils.Dictionary;

  import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
  import mx.collections.IList;

  [Event(name="collectionChange", type="mx.events.CollectionEvent")]

  public class Collection implements IEventDispatcher, IList {

    /** Internal collection. */
    private var _collection:ArrayCollection;

    /** Dictionary for fast id lookup. */
    private var _dictionary:Dictionary;

    /** @inheritDoc */
    public function get length():int {
      return this._collection.length;
    }

    /**
     * The constructor.
     *
     * @param collection The default collection.
     */
    public function Collection(collection:ArrayCollection = null) {
      this._collection = collection || new ArrayCollection();
      this._dictionary = new Dictionary();
    }

    /** @inheritDoc */
    public function addEventListener(type:String,
                                     listener:Function,
                                     useCapture:Boolean = false,
                                     priority:int = 0,
                                     useWeakReference:Boolean = false):void {
      this._collection.addEventListener(type, listener, useCapture, priority, useWeakReference);
    }

    /** @inheritDoc */
    public function dispatchEvent(event:Event):Boolean {
      return this._collection.dispatchEvent(event);
    }

    /** @inheritDoc */
    public function removeEventListener(type:String,
                                        listener:Function,
                                        useCapture:Boolean = false):void {
      this._collection.removeEventListener(type, listener, useCapture);
    }

    /** @inheritDoc */
    public function hasEventListener(type:String):Boolean {
      return this._collection.hasEventListener(type);
    }

    /** @inheritDoc */
    public function willTrigger(type:String):Boolean {
      return this._collection.willTrigger(type);
    }

    /** @inheritDoc */
    public function addItem(item:Object):void {
      this._dictionary[item.id] = item;
      this._collection.addItem(item);
    }

    /** @inheritDoc */
    public function addItemAt(item:Object,
                              index:int):void {
      this._dictionary[item.id] = item;
      this._collection.addItemAt(item, index)
    }

    /** @inheritDoc */
    public function getItemAt(index:int,
                              prefetch:int = 0):Object {
      return this._collection.getItemAt(index, prefetch);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the object associated with the given id.
     * @param id The id of the object.
     * @return The object associated with the given id, null else.
     */
    public function getItemById(id:String):Object {
      return _dictionary[id];
    }

    /** @inheritDoc */
    public function getItemIndex(item:Object):int {
      return this._collection.getItemIndex(item);
    }

    /** @inheritDoc */
    public function itemUpdated(item:Object,
                                property:Object = null,
                                oldValue:Object = null,
                                newValue:Object = null):void {
      this._collection.itemUpdated(item, property, oldValue, newValue);
    }

    /** @inheritDoc */
    public function removeAll():void {
      this._collection.removeAll();
      this._dictionary = new Dictionary();
    }

    /** @inheritDoc */
    public function removeItemAt(index:int):Object {
      const object:Object = this._collection.removeItemAt(index);
      delete _dictionary[object.id];
      return object;
    }

    /** @inheritDoc */
    public function setItemAt(item:Object,
                              index:int):Object {
      this._dictionary[item.id] = item;
      this._collection.setItemAt(item, index);
    }

    /** @inheritDoc */
    public function toArray():Array {
      this._collection.toArray();
    }
  }
}
```

This would provide an access by id.

Comment: thx for reply, im working with markers.xml `<marker id="1" adress="address="myMD2Models/testHouseMD2.md2"</marker> ` its used to load models in scene, using that kind of method  `particles_ary[prevIndex].load(myDataGrid.dataProvider.getItemAt(0).address,myCarSkin, 10, 3);`

Comment: Hey Florian, i get error using getById, it tells me there is no propertie -object(its not declared), and i dont rly get how do i use it in DataProvider, like change dataProvider.getById("20") if so how do i point for an object that i need cause in these array(dataprovider) are multiple objects like address,name,id, and other ? still can't get it =((

Comment: Are you using Flex or just Flash?

Comment: im using this http://pastebin.com/nfuC1Hzy, i guess i found a possible way to fix this, but i dont rly get how to do it, whole point is to - parse/sort specified item from .xml markers, item = "id", and to assing its value = to index of the object that it was retrivied, like when sorter get to object(A).item(id) its assigns to Object(A).Index(item(id)), but i dont rly get how to do it in code ? can you help me out

Answer (score 0):

anyway i fixed this 
articles_ary[prevIndex].load(markers.@value);

I didnt need to use DataProvider and etc, damnn im nooobb.
thx for help anyway

Comment: You might want to check out my last change.